# How to fix Unboxing may produce nullPointer Exception with firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]No matter which user I am logged in as the "points" variable is always returned as 0. The same code works on separate activities and I cannot see what is different. When I hover over the datasnapshot is says that is may produce null pointer exception but it also says this on the other activities that work. I have spent ages trying out figure this out. Thanks.

```
        databaseUsers =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        databaseUsers.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            points = dataSnapshot.child(user.getUid()).child("points").getValue(int.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    //Getting Total Points from Firebase Database
    databaseUsers.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            totalpoints = dataSnapshot.child(user.getUid()).child("totalpoints").getValue(int.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: have you tried with Integer.class?

Comment: show your data model

Comment: I have added the structure of the data on firebase

Comment: try to log.d(TAG,"user id is "+user.getUid());

Comment: When I log that is comes up as "user id is: wrju0AEIAWQRkgbX98nSOe5pPa83" Which matches the user I am meant to be logged in as

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I assume that this is the line you're talking about, and that `points` is of some primitive type, such as `int` or `long`:

> ```
> points = dataSnapshot.child(user.getUid()).child("points").getValue(int.class);
> ```

The problem here is that [`.getValue(Class<T>)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getValue(java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)) returns a boxed type, for example `Integer` which may be `null`, when the data point doesn't exist. If you try to assign the returned value to a primitive type, the value needs to be unboxed, and unboxing a `null` value results in a null pointer exception.

To protect in case of `null` values, you need to add a `null`-check:

```
Integer value = dataSnapshot.child(user.getUid()).child("points").getValue(int.class);
if (value != null) {
    points = value;
} else {
    // TODO
    // points = ???
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this has removed the comment made by android studio however for some reason, the points variables that it is getting from the database is always returning as 0. It never crashed prior to the changes I have made (Thanks to your helpful advice) :) but it was always returning the value as 0. and it still is :(.

Comment: @ChristianWebb so your main question is not about the "unboxing might result in null pointer exception", but actually "why the method always returns 0", right?

Comment: Well It was both, this has fixed the null pointer exception however the issue that prevents the app working is why it returns 0.